# Is US salary taxable in India and is there any provision to save tax?

Tags: united-states, taxes, india, non-resident, dtaa

I have this question about the tax filing that I am planning to do in India for year 2013-14.

I worked in India for an Indian company for almost 7 months and I also worked 4 months in the US (as a US resident for US employer) in the same financial year. Following are the details of months that I worked in India and US.

- 2013 April: 15 days in US and 10 days in India
- 2013 May to 2013 September worked in India
- 2013 October and November, I didn’t work but I was in India
- 2013 December 9th to 2014 March 31, I worked in the US.

Since I have been in India for more than 182 days, I will have to file taxes for all the incomes in India. So, my question is, should I have to consider my US salary also as income ? My US salary was credited to US bank account.

Answer (score 1):

For the financial year 1 April 2013 to 31 March 2014 as you have stayed more than 182 days in India, you are deemed resident for tax purposes. You Global income would be taxed [it does not matter whether you have transferred the funds to India or not].

India and US have [DTAA](http://www.incometaxindia.gov.in/Pages/international-taxation/dtaa.aspx) and you can claim relief to the extent of taxes paid.